# Use both "data" and "response" attributes in ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to use both the php response and ajax data in the following `complete` function. Is that possible? I can do things with just `function(response)` or `function(data)` but would like to have both available.

```
function fxn() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { foo: document.getElementById('elementID').value },
        complete: function(response, data) { //doesn't work
            if(response.responseText == data.foo) {
                //do stuff
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            //handle
        },
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data is just the one of the properties in the JSON required by `$.ajax`, it's not a variable.

You can define a variable outside the ajax call and then pass it the the ajax method.
If you do that, you will be able to read it later. :)

```
 function fxn() {

    var dataToSend= { foo: document.getElementById('elementID').value }

    $.ajax({
        url:'script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataToSend,
        complete: function(response) { //doesn't work
            if(response.responseText == dataToSend.foo) {
                //do stuff
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            //handle
        },
    });
    return false;
}
```